# Fetch data from website in Windows store app using HttpClient

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I am developing an App on the Windows store 8 through C# and XAML where I need to retrieve data from any website and display it on my app.

I am Using `HttpClient` class and am able to get the HTML code behind the webpage.

My app can be considered to be similar to weather apps where the climatic conditions are retrieved from a website and displayed on my app screen.

How to go further? Which class should I use?

Comment: If you need to retrieve information from web pages (not display whole web page in your application): proper way to get data from web sites will be to use *Web Services* instead of parsing raw HTML.

Comment: Yes! @AndriiKalytiiuk i want to retrieve only certain information.

Comment: You would better to explore Web Services capabilities for Web sites you are going to retrieve information from. If they provide no Web Services - you will need to implement direct HTML parsing and that is another question, you can search it in Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for [WebView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227702.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To get HTML page content and parse it in your application use `HtmlWeb` and `HtmlDocument` classes:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = await web.LoadFromWebAsync("https://example.com");
```

Then to eg. to get content of element with specified id you can write:

```
var a = doc.GetElementbyId("element-id").innertext;
```

You can find more useful methods in [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument_methods(v=vs.110).aspx).